# Convert Simple array to below result array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using php

Below is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Q .
    [1] => What are the factors of x2+2x+1?
    [2] => A .
    [3] => (x+1)
    [4] => B .
    [5] => (x-1)
    [6] => C .
    [7] => (2x+1)
    [8] => D .
    [9] => (2x-1)
    [10] => S .
    [11] => (x+1)
    [12] => M.
    [13] => 20
    [14] => Q .
    [15] => Test  are the factors of x2-2x+1?
    [16] => A .
    [17] => (x+1)
    [18] => B .
    [19] => (x-1)
    [20] => C .
    [21] => (2x+1)
    [22] => D .
    [23] => (2x-1)
    [24] => S .
    [25] => (x-1)
    [26] => M.
    [27] => 5
)
```

And i want result in

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question] => What are the factors of x2+2x+1?
            [A.] => (x+1)
            [B.] => (x-1)
            [C.] => (2x+1)
            [D.] => (2x-1)
            [S.] => (x+1)
            [M.] => 20
        )

 [0] => Array
        (
            [question] => TEST What are the factors of x2+2x+1?
            [A.] => (x+1)
            [B.] => (x-1)
            [C.] => (2x+1)
            [D.] => (2x-1)
            [S.] => (x+1)
            [M.] => 
        )

)
```

Please Advise.

Comment: Write code to do it. That usually works best.

Comment: You want two Array[0] ? That's gonna be a though one. They tend to overwrite each other.

Comment: Why are you asking for help in really basic PHP code ? learn coding.

Comment: @user... you are getting a lot of feedback on this partly because you are starting with a seemingly arbitrary (and very bad) data structure without much explanation at all of your business problem.  Although the community is not here to develop software from scratch for you (you'll need to make some of the effort), it is even more frustrating to be presented something like this with very little context.  Perhaps you can update your post with a short but clear description of your overall objective.

Comment: Also, if you have code already which presumably produces that questionable "input array", if you post your code, you may get suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$array = Array
(
    0 =>  "Q .",
    1 =>  "What are the factors of x2+2x+1?",
    2 =>  "A .",
    3 =>  "(x+1)",
    4 =>  "B .",
    5 =>  "(x-1)",
    6 =>  "C .",
    7 =>  "(2x+1)",
    8 =>  "D .",
    9 =>  "(2x-1)",
    10 => "S ." ,
    11 => "(x+1)" ,
    12 => "M." ,
    13 => "20" ,
    14 => "Q ." ,
    15 => "Test  are the factors of x2-2x+1?" ,
    16 => "A ." ,
    17 => "(x+1)" ,
    18 => "B ." ,
    19 => "(x-1)" ,
    20 => "C ." ,
    21 => "(2x+1)" ,
    22 => "D ." ,
    23 => "(2x-1)" ,
    24 => "S ." ,
    25 => "(x-1)" ,
    26 => "M." ,
    27 => "5" ,
);

$keys = array(
    'question','A. ','B. ','C. ','D. ','S. ','M. '
);

$result = array_map(
    function($q) use ($keys) {
        return array_combine($keys, $q);  // 4. make our keys the keys of each resulting array
    },
    array_chunk(
        array_map(
            function($a){
                return $a[1];      // 2. select only the 2nd part of the chunk
            },
            array_chunk($array, 2) // 1. split initial array into chunks of 2
        )
    ,7)                            // 3. split it into chunks of 7
);
```